# Green's function of a bounded domain is strictly negative

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

I have been struggling with this proof for half a day. I am really baffled. The result of my proof is close but not exactly the same as the proposal.

Here is the question:
[image]

Here is my proof:
[image]

The proposal is $G<0$, but what my proof arrives at $G\le0$. Where did I go wrong? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Details may depend on the definition of Green's function you are using, but here are the key points:

1. Fix $y$. The function $h(x) = G(\cdot,y)$ is harmonic in $\Omega\setminus \{y\}$
2. Since $G(x,y)\to-\infty$ as $x\to y$, there is $r>0$ such that $h(x)<0$ when $|x-y|\le r$.
3. Apply the strong form of the maximum principle to $h$ on $\Omega \setminus \{x: |x-y|\le r\}$. Since $h\le 0$ on the boundary, and is not constant (being strictly negative on the circle $|x-y|=r$), it follows that $h<0$ on $\Omega \setminus \{x: |x-y|\le r\}$

Comment: Thanks so much! I don't understand the second point. Why the Green function goes to negative infinity? And why such a $r$ exist?

Comment: You never stated the definition of Green's function that you are using (FYI: there are many different functions by this name: depending on definition, they may be positive, negative, or change sign). I replied on the assumption that in the formula  $G(x,y)=\Gamma(x-y)+h_y(x)$ that you wrote, $\Gamma$ is something like $-c/|x-y|^{n-2}$, which goes to $-\infty$ when $x\to y$.

Comment: The strong law says $u$ is harmonic and attains either maximum or minimum in $\Omega$ then it is constant. I also don't understand how the strong form of maximum principle can get $h<0$?

Comment: The maximum principle says $h\le 0$... and then excludes the possibility of $h=0$, leaving us with...

Comment: Yes! That is exactly the definition I am using. I got the second step. Thanks so much! But I still don't understand the third step. Why the strong form of maximum principle can get $h<0$?

Comment: Okay, what *can* you get from the maximum principle, applying it in this situation?

Comment: Is it because $h<0$ on the boundary $|x-y|=r$, then $h<0$ in the area $\Omega $\{x:|x-y|<r}, because the maximum principle says it attains its maximum on the boundary? And the area in side the ball {x:|x-y|<r} is already negative because step 2. So the domain is negative?

Comment: This is now what I wrote in item 3. Check again on what domain the maximum principle should be applied. Also... this is not three, but even four strikes [comments], so I'm out.