# Why is my solution "not enough"?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, proof-verification

The question is as follows

> Let $G(x,y)$ be the Green's function for a bounded domain $\Omega$. Prove that $G(x,y)<0$.

My solution is in the following picture, where the professor marks "This is not enough". I have been thinking about it for a long time but could not figure it out what I am missing. Hope someone can help me with this. Thank you!

**My proof**:

Given a bounded domain $\Omega$ and a fixed point $y$ in $\Omega$, the Gamma function (the fundamental solution of Laplacian) is defined as $\Gamma (x - y) = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\frac{1}{{n(2 - n){\omega _n}}}{{\left\| {x - y} \right\|}^{2 - n}}}&{n > 2}\\
{\frac{1}{{2\pi}}\log \left\| {x - y} \right\|}&{n = 2}
\end{array}} \right.$ and Gamma function is harmonic in $\Omega$ \ $B_r(y)$ for arbitrary small radius $r$ and obviously goes to $-\infty$ as $x\rightarrow y$.

Green function is defined as $G(x,y)=\Gamma(x-y)+h_y(x)$ where $h_y(x)$ (a function varies with different $y$) satisfies $h_y(x)=-\Gamma(x-y)$ on $\partial \Omega$ and is harmonic in $\Omega$.

Since by definition $h_y(x)$ is harmonic in the whole $\Omega$ so it is bounded (by $\sup h_y $ and $\inf h_y $ on $\partial \Omega$). Thus it is obvious that the Green function goes to negative infinity as $x \rightarrow y$. Thus there exists a small $r$ such that the Green function is negative on $\partial B_r(y)$.

Now that I have proved there exists a negative boundary $B_r(y)$ around the small hole $y$ and the outer boundary of a Green function is zero, so the Green function in $\{ x \in \Omega |\left| x \right| > r\} $ is negative. The Green function is negative when $\left| x \right| \le r$, so it is negative in the entire domain $\Omega $.

I don't know what I am missing.

[image]

Comment: While that text is legible, it's barely so. If you could transcribe the notes into text+TeX (and maybe highlight the part that your professor suggests is not enough) that would be immensely helpful.

Comment: For context, here is the original proof outline that OP used for the assignment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948869/greens-function-of-a-bounded-domain-is-strictly-negative

Comment: I think the text is very easily readable

Comment: @grdgfgr Good for you. My eyes disagree, though.

Comment: @Clement C. I have updated my question with a detailed proof in latex and changed for a more clear picture.

Comment: Unless I'm overlooking it, at the place where the professor said "This is not enough", you did not mention that $G(x,y) = 0$ for $x\in \partial \Omega$. You mention that in the typed proof here, but not in the hand-written one in the picture. But that is important. Additionally, it might be that the professor expected you to state that $G(\,\cdot\,,y)$ is not constant, and hence does not attain its maximum in $\Omega\setminus \{ x : \lVert x-y\rVert \leqslant r\}$, so is strictly negative there.

Comment: @ClementC. you do realize that you can enlarge it? https://i.stack.imgur.com/JI3hh.jpg

Comment: @grdgfgr: Yes, and yet. Also, you do realize that external content (not hosted on Math.SE) has no perennial guarantee? A dead hotlink in 3 weeks would make the whole question a tad trickier to understand.